# Go ReplaceAllString

Tags: regex, go

I read the example code from [golang.org website](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#example_Regexp_ReplaceAllString). Essentially the code looks like this:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile("a(x*)b")
fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString("-ab-axxb-", "T"))
fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString("-ab-axxb-", "$1"))
fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString("-ab-axxb-", "$1W"))
fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString("-ab-axxb-", "${1}W"))
```

The output is like this:

```
-T-T-
--xx-
---
-W-xxW-
```

I understand the first output, but I don't understand the the rest three. Can someone explain to me the results 2,3 and 4. Thanks.

Comment: Did you read the text immediately above the example code?

Comment: Yes, I read. But I still don't understand how the expansion works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most intriguing is the `fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString("-ab-axxb-", "$1W"))` line. The [docs say](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#example_Regexp_ReplaceAllString):

> Inside repl, `$` signs are interpreted as in `Expand`

And [Expand](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.Expand) says:

> In the template, a variable is denoted by a substring of the form `$name` or `${name}`, where name is a non-empty sequence of letters, digits, and underscores.
> **A reference to an out of range or unmatched index or a name that is not present in the regular expression is replaced with an empty slice.**
>
> **In the `$name` form, name is taken to be as long as possible: `$1x` is equivalent to `${1x}`, not `${1}x`, and, `$10` is equivalent to `${10}`, not `${1}0`.**

So, in the 3rd replacement, `$1W` is treated as `${1W}` and since this group is not initialized, an empty string is used for replacement.

When I say "the group is not initialized", I mean to say that the group is not defined in the regex pattern, thus, it was not populated during the *match* operation. *Replacing* means getting all matches and then they are replaced with the replacement pattern. *Backreferences* (`$xx` constructs) are populated during the *matching* phase. The `$1W` group is missing in the pattern, thus, it was not populated during *matching*, and only an empty string is used when *replacing* phase occurs.

The 2nd and 4th replacements are easy to understand and have been described in the above answers. Just `$1` backreferences the characters *captured* with the first capturing group (the subpattern enclosed with a pair of unescaped parentheses), same is with Example 4.

**You can think of `{}` as a means to *disambiguate* the replacement pattern.**

Now, if you need to make the results consistent, use a **named capture** `(?P<1W>....)`:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile("a(?P<1W>x*)b")  // <= See here, pattern updated
fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString("-ab-axxb-", "T"))
fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString("-ab-axxb-", "$1"))
fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString("-ab-axxb-", "$1W"))
fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString("-ab-axxb-", "${1}W"))
```

Results:

```
-T-T-
--xx-
--xx-
-W-xxW-
```

The 2nd and 3rd lines now produce consistent output since the named group `1W` is also *the first* group, and `$1` numbered backreference points to the same text captured with a named capture `$1W`.

Comment: What did you mean by `this group is not initialized`? How to initialize a group? I'm sorry my question might be naïve.

Comment: The group is not specified in the regex pattern, thus, it was not *populated* during the match operation. Replacing means getting all matches and then they are replaced with the replacement pattern. *Backreferences* (`$xx` constructs) are populated during the *matching* phase. The `$1W` group is missing in the pattern, thus, it was not populated during matching, and only an empty string is used when replacing phase occurs.

Comment: What should be done to make $1W present if I want? I'm trying to get educated about the named group.

Comment: Use `re := regexp.MustCompile("a(?P<1W>x*)b")`, then, you will have the same result with lines 2 and 3. I updated the answer with it.

Answer (score 2):

$number or $name is  index of subgroup in regex or subgroup name

```
fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString("-ab-axxb-", "$1"))
```

$1 is subgroup 1 in regex = `x*`

```
fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString("-ab-axxb-", "$1W"))
```

$1W no subgroup name 1W => Replace all with null

```
fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString("-ab-axxb-", "${1}W"))
```

$1 and ${1} is the same. replace all subgroup 1  with W

for more information : https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain the second result a bit more?

Comment: Ok,$name all character after $ is name, so there are no replace key => replace key = null, if not find group name it will use default regex a(x*)b and replace with null key

Comment: Thank you for getting me educated about the named group.

Answer (score 2):

`$1` is a shorthand for `${1}`

`${1}` is the value of the first (1) group, e.g. the content of the first pair of (). This group is `(x*)` i.e. any number of `x`.

`ReplaceAllString` replaces every match. There are two matches. The first is `ab`, the second is `axxb`.

No 2. replaces any match with the content of the group: This is "" in the first match and "xx" in the second.

No 4. adds a "W" after the content of the group.

No 3. Is left as an exercise. Hint: The twelfth capturing group would be $12.

Comment: So can I understand as that the replacement is dynamic for each match?

Comment: Thank you. You answer helped me to understand the second output.

Comment: We are not writing a math book here with leaving stuff as an exercise.