# How golang replace string by regex group?

Tags: regex, go, regex-group

I want to use regex group to replace string in `golang`, just like as follow in `python`:

```
re.sub(r"(\d.*?)[a-z]+(\d.*?)", r"\1 \2", "123abc123") # python code
```

So how do I implement this in golang?

Comment: Also, [Go ReplaceAllString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34673039/go-replaceallstring/34673443#34673443) is interesting :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `$1`, `$2`, etc in replacement. For example:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`(foo)`)
s := re.ReplaceAllString("foo", "$1$1")
fmt.Println(s)
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/ZHoz-X1scf.

Docs: https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.ReplaceAllString.